# Store single json from azure iot hub to datalake2

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-iot-hub, azure-data-lake-gen2

I added iot hub and devices. All data from iot hub is saved to data lake 2 in json format. Works fine but if there are several messages at once from device, it is saved in a single json. It causes some troubles... Is there a way to save each message-event in a separate json? I've looked through settings of iot hub but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such as settings for always forwarding a single message to the storage in the IoT Hub routing mechanism. Basically this requirement can be implemented by azure function either in the stream pipeline consumer (*IoTHubTrigger*) or in the event grid subscriber (*EventGridTrigger*).

**Update:**

The following is an example of the *IoTHubTrigger* function with an output blob binding to the container of the Data Lake Storage Gen2:

run.csx:

```csharp
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async Task Run(EventData ed, CloudBlockBlob outputBlob, ILogger log)
{   
    //log.LogInformation($"DeviceId = {ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]}\r\n{JObject.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ed.Body))}");  

    var msg = new { 
        EnqueuedTimeUtc = ed.SystemProperties["iothub-enqueuedtime"],
        Properties = ed.Properties,
        SystemProperties = new {
          connectionDeviceId = ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"], 
          connectionAuthMethod = ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-auth-method"],
          connectionDeviceGenerationId = ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-auth-generation-id"],
          enqueuedTime = ed.SystemProperties["iothub-enqueuedtime"]   
        },
        Body = JObject.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ed.Body))
    };

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
    await outputBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream(buffer));

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

function.json:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "ed",
      "connection": "rk2020iot_IOTHUB",
      "eventHubName": "rk2020iot_IOTHUBNAME",
      "consumerGroup": "function",
      "cardinality": "one",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "eventHubTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "iot/rk2020iot/{DateTime}.json",
      "connection": "rk2020datalake2_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide examples or links?

Comment: I have added an example of the IoTHubTrigger function to store each telemetry data to the blob file of the container of the data lake storage gen2.